# не работает ajax запрос на добавление в избранное

Tags: python-3.x, ajax, django

При нажатии на добавление статьи в избранное ничего не происходит, а в консоли появляется ошибка:

```
    Internal Server Error: /favorites/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/finn/Документы/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/finn/Документы/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/finn/Документы/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: add_to_favorites() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

**views:**

```
def add_to_favorites(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not request.session.get('favorites'):
            request.session['favorites'] = list()
        else:
            request.session['favorites'] = list(request.session['favorites'])

        item_exist = next((item for item in request.session['favorites'] if
                            item['type'] == request.POST.get('type') and
                            item['id'] == id), False)

        add_data = {
            'type': request.POST.get('type'),
            'id': id,
        }

        if not item_exist:
            request.session['favorites'].append(add_data)
            request.session.modified = True

    if request.is_ajax():
        data = {
            'type': request.POST.get('type'),
            'id': request.POST.get('id'),
        }
        request.session.modified = True
        return JsonResponse(data)
    return redirect(request.POST.get('url_from'))


def remove_from_favorites(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for item in request.session['favorites']:
            if item['id'] == id and item['type'] == request.POST.get('type'):
                item.clear()

        while {} in request.session['favorites']:
            request.session['favorites'].remove({})

        if not request.session['favorites']:
            del request.session['favorites']

        request.session.modified = True
    if request.is_ajax():
        data = {
            'type': request.POST.get('type'),
            'id': request.POST.get('id'),
        }
        request.session.modified = True
        return JsonResponse(data)
    return redirect(request.POST.get('url_from'))

def favorites_api(request):
    return JsonResponse(request.session.get('favorites'), safe=False)
```

**urls.py:**

```
path('add/', add_to_favorites, name='add'),
path('remove/', remove_from_favorites, name='remove'),
path('api/', favorites_api, name='api'),
```

**ajax.js:**

```
function getCookie(name){
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '')
        {
            let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
            {
                let cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '='))
                {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // Для этих методов токен не будет подставляться в заголовок.
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method))
 }

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: (xhr, settings) => {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
         }
    }
})


const add_to_favorites_url = '/favorites/add/'
const remove_from_favorites_url = '/favorites/remove/'
const favorites_api_url = '/favorites/api/'
const added_to_favorites_class = 'added'


function add_to_favorites(){
    $('.add-to-favorites').each((index, el) => {
        $(el).click((e) => {
            e.preventDefault()

            const type = $(el).data('type')
            const id = $(el).data('id')

            if( $(e.target).hasClass(added_to_favorites_class) ) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: remove_from_favorites_url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        type: type,
                        id: id,
                    },
                    success: (data) => {
                        $(el).removeClass(added_to_favorites_class)
                    }
                })
            } else {

                $.ajax({
                    url: add_to_favorites_url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:{
                        type: type,
                        id: id,
                    },
                    success: (data) => {
                        $(el).addClass(added_to_favorites_class)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}


function get_session_favorites() {

    $.getJSON(favorites_api_url, (json) => {
        if (json !== null) {
            for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                $('.add-to-favorites').each((index, el) => {
                    const type = $(el).data('type')
                    const id = $(el).data('id')

                    if ( json[i].type == type && json[i].id == id ){
                        $(el).addClass(added_to_favorites_class)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    add_to_favorites()
})
```

html:

```
<div class="add-to-favorites" style="cursor:pointer;" data-type="{{ type }}" data-id="{{ id }}">
    add
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path('add/<int:id>', add_to_favorites, name='add'),
```

То же самое с остальными. Функция ожидает на вход параметр id, который не приходит.
Ну и const add_to_favorites_url = '/favorites/add/<тут_id_должен_быть>'

Comment: Ajax выполняется теперь, но вместо конкретного числа id он берет строку 'id'

Comment: это проблема с резолвером джанги. Поэтому, если мы знаем нужный нам тип, то лучше привести к нему. Например 
```
and item['id'] == int(id)

Comment: Проблема решена, у меня во вьюхе было обращение и сравнение с обычной переменной `id`, а надо было использовать `request.POST.get('id')`

Comment: тогда входной параметр id во вьюхах лишний